# SaveAs() doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I 'm trying to open an excel file that already exist, do some operations and the save the excel file with the same name.

```
var xls = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
xls.visible = true;
xls.DisplayAlerts=false;
var wb=xls.Workbooks.Open("C:\\test.xls");
xls.Range("A1","B1").Interior.ColorIndex=37;
xls.Range("C1","D1").Interior.ColorIndex=37;
xls.Range("A1:D1").Merge();
wb.SaveAs("C:\\test.xls");
xls.Quit();
```

Bu, im not able to save, i'm been promptd sayin file already exist, do u want to save, etc...
Any suggestion pls...

---

I changed my code as below:

```
var xls = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
xls.visible = true;
xls.DisplayAlerts=false;
var wb=xls.Workbooks.Open("C:\\test.xls");
xls.Range("A1","B1").Interior.ColorIndex=37;
xls.Range("C1","D1").Interior.ColorIndex=37;
xls.Range("A1:D1").Merge();
wb.SaveAs("C:\\newTest.xls");
xls.Quit();
```

The file is now saved, but the problem is with formatting.
The original file test.xls is a tab delimited file saved as .xls file.
after doing some modifications to the file saving as newTest.xls, when I try to open, it says that the formatting is not good and do you want to open? when I click yes, it opens the file but without the modifications done.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `JavaScript`? Seriously?

Comment: if you want to make just changes then just save it don't saveas it if you want to saveas it the you have to delete first file

Comment: the prompt says it, the file already exists!

Comment: @PraveenKumar - better than **VBS** any day of the year

Comment: LoL. @JaromandaX The OP had tagged as `JavaScript` I am not sure, it looks like `vba`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - hmmmmm my bad, thought it was WSH jscript :p

Comment: @ WisdmLabs, just save also does'nt save the file. It prompts, file already exists and do u want to save... I just want to avoid all the prompt and save the file with the changes.

Comment: use `application.DisplayAlerts = False` then `wb.save` after that `Application.DisplayAlerts = true`

Comment: I tried with DisplayAlerts, but does'nt save

Comment: @GBI where are you coding this in? as VBA doesn't require you to put a `;` at the end of every line

Comment: @PraveenKumar seems the `Javascript` tag was correct as its being coded in `Javascript` ;)

Comment: @GBI Sorry then buddy.

Comment: @Praveen, no problem

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save the file with the same name. 
To do this don't use `SaveAs` but instead use the regular `Save`.